# Cannot test Grails application which has oauth autontication inside LAN

Tags: grails, oauth, google-oauth

I have a Grails project which I want to test in a Local network, but the problem is that I use OAuth for signing in and have specified localhost as my redirect URL to Google app which works fine on a single machine, but when other PC's try to use my app google returns the token to their PC because they are the it returning to localhost. I tried to specify My IP address to google redirect URL but it doesn't allow because it's not a public IP address. So does anyone have any suggestion on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have a domain name specifying the redirect url if your app goes out of your local environment(in your case to google.com).so the solution is test all aspects of ur app besides the login in ur lan enviroment